# Let A be the set of rational numbers in the open interval (0,7).

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let A be the set of rational numbers in the open interval (0,7) and $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a uniformly continuous function. Which of the following are correct.

A. f is bounded

B. f is necessarily a constant function

C. f is differentiable on (0,7)

D. f is differentiable at all rational points in (0,7)

**my attempt :**  f is bounded , because every uniformly continuous is bounded

what about other options

Answer (score 3):

You need a little bit more for that first statement: every uniformly continuous function *on a bounded domain* is bounded.

For a counterexample to b,c,d, consider $f(x) = |x-4|$.

Comment: Will the function provided by you differentiable except $x=4$?

Comment: Suppose the statement in option D is $f$ differentiable at all irrational points in (0,1). Will the statement true?

Answer (score 0):

Hint :consider the example $f(x)=xsin\frac {1}{x}$ and use to show that $B,C,D$ are false